# Angular2 - Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to run a basic Angular2 app. However currently running into the following error when I run the app with `live-server` and `npm start`:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined`

[image]

I have the latest Angular2 npm installed. Here is my markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/systemjs/systemjs/0.19.6/dist/system.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>

        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <first-comp></first-comp>
    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js file:

```
var FirstComponent = ng.
    Component({
        selector: 'first-comp'  
    })
    .View({
        template: '<h2>I am learning {{ myFramework }}</h2>'
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {
            this.myFramework = "Angular2";
        }
    });

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.bootstrap(firstComponent);
});
```

Comment: First you have twice `angular2.dev.js`, second if you want to write in ES5 you should use one of the `umd` bundles. Check this [table](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/builds-js/bundles/overview.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

you are missing the boot.js file which bootstrap's the whole thing before you start using it, in your file you are using the `ng` object before the DOM has loaded (`DOMContentLoaded`). That's why you have the wrapper on:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.bootstrap(firstComponent);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, the tuts course is totally useless at this point :( I can't continue... trying the 5 minute install

Comment: Lol, this is definitely NOT a `5 minute` install, posting new question soon

Comment: Yup lol... mind a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730010/angular2-5-minute-install-bug-require-is-not-defined