# Javascript critical error when running Angular 2 application

Tags: angular

I have an ASP.NET 5 and Angular 2 setup that was created using the steps I outlined [in this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584335/angular-2-application-not-working-in-an-asp-net-5-environment)

This all has been working great, but all of a sudden I've been getting errors when running the application, all these errors are related to the js files needed to run Angular 2. Any ideas what can be causing this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update**

I'm only getting these errors when running in IE 11, when I change the browser to Chrome it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I started getting this error following a Windows 10 update. By default my browser was set to Internet Explorer

[image]

I changed this tho Chrome and my application started working. My next step was to reset all my Internet Explorer settings by going to the Tools > Internet Options menu and clicking on the advanced tab

[image]

I changed my browser in Visual Studion back to Internet Explorer and my application started working.