# <script> tag to connect Angular2 app to HTML page

Tags: angular

Here is my try to make minimal Angular2 app.

I expect that `<h1>Hello Angular</h1>` to appear instead of `<my-app>Loading?</my-app>`.

app.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading?</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

app.ts:

```ts
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular';
}

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages"
  ]
}
```

Currently, I'm getting

```
app.ts:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at app.ts:1
```

I suspect that there is some script I should add to my HTML page with `require` function. Or, maybe, I have to enable some typescript settings to make everything transpile into single js file.

As an additional question, I'd like to reduce this code as much as possible. Do I really need that module and that bootstrapping work to make component work? Do I really need `tsconfig.json` at all?

## Update

I gave up, made use of https://github.com/angular/quickstart.

What I don't like is that I have to load several scripts, purpose of which I don't understand: why shims, zones are to be loaded by script tag, why I cannot load `main.js` this way, etc...

By now it works. I'll use it as starting point.

Comment: Did you read the complete details about setting up angular 2 application?

Comment: Did you use angular-cli?

Comment: @Aravind I read a lot of tutorials and docs. I would be very thankful if you point me to some page with exhaustive explanation how I can quickly make simplest Angular2 web page.

Comment: @Edric No, I don't. I know that such tool exists but cannot understand why I need it.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Have a look at this blog [**Rangle.io**](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/)

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Then what tool did you use to start or serve the application?

Comment: @Edric I typed it by hand and copy-pasted some lines.

Comment: @GeorgeSovetov Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730010/angular2-5-minute-install-bug-require-is-not-defined

Comment: @Edric Saw this question too. It's related to beta version which differs from final one. Particularly in how it's written in `package.json` and bootstrapped.